# Are there any standard Command line conventions for dashes and arguments?

Tags: java, python, unix, command-line-arguments

What are the command-line conventions regarding when to use 2 dashes, 1 dash, or simply no options at all and simply read inputs in order?

I realize there are many variants, but do any conventions stand out as the industry standard  (say in Java, or C, or Python)?

Comment: many times, single dash is shortcut of a similar option. E.g. `./cassandra.sh -h hostname` is equivalent to double dashed version `./cassandra.sh --host hostname`

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html and also http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7903006/440558

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read up on the [background section](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#background) of Python's optparse module, it answers some of your questions and exemplifies with some common argument formatting standards seen in the wild. The optparse module author recommends a style that roughly corresponds to the [POSIX conventions for command line arguments](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/attributes/_posix.html), with the addition of --double-dashed-long-arguments which comes from the GNU coding standard.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your taste.

Unix convention is that commands have 2 forms: long and short (one character). To indicate long form we use 2 dashes --. For example `--install`. Short form is marked with one dash, e.g. `-i`.

But there is no rules without exceptions. For example command line option of java itself do not follow this convention: `-cp` and `-classpath` mean the same and both are marked with one dash only. `-version` does not have short alias etc.

Slashes are used in windows applications.

I as a java developer prefer to use platform independent conventions (dashes). Moreover various libraries (like [cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) from jakarta project) supports dashes, so it is easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Nishant, the single dash is a shorthand notation of a more verbose option.
See the ls Example given by Apache Commons CLI http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html#ls_Example